# Facebook post integration with my app gives error 191 redirect_uri is not owned by the application

Tags: facebook

I have an application running on my localhost. I registered this app on facebook with the siteUrl as http://IP:port/app_context

I got the APP Id and when i try to invoke the feed API of facebook , i get the following error :

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

The code to invoke FB is :

```
<body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
      </script>
      <script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'294615097233384', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });

         FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
            message: 'Send Message to FB'});
      </script>
     </body>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have stream post security enabled in the app's advanced settings?
If not, that message should only be appearing if you're authenticating a user and sending them to a redirect_url which doesn't match what you've configured in the app settings